# Bitbucket Artifact not pupulating files to next step

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, artifacts

I am doing a bitbucket pipeline with 2 steps, build and deploy.  After build I need the generated file in the next step, but artifact is not working as expected. Even though the folder I am creating ("build") is in the next step, the file inside the folder is not.
This is my pipeline:

```
image: ibmcom/iib
pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: build
          script:
          - . /opt/ibm/iib-10.0.0.11/server/bin/mqsiprofile
          - . /opt/ibm/iib-10.0.0.11/server/bin/mqsipackagebar -a pipelineGenerated.bar -w . -k $PROJECT_NAME
          - mkdir -p $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/build
          - cp pipelineGenerated.bar $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/build/pipelineGenerated.bar
          - ls -l $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/build
          artifacts:
            - build/**
      - step:
          name: OverrideBar
          script:
          - ls -l $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/buildere
```

As you can see I run "ls -l" in both steps to check the content of "build" folder and this is the output:
Step1:
[image]
[image]

If I download the artifacts, It actually has the pipelineGenerated.bar file
But, in step2, when I need that file, this is the ls -s output

[image]

Any ideas? I've been dealing with this the whole day...
Thanks!!

Comment: Your script looks correct... Try removing all mention of `$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR` since you already are in that dir. Also, try specifying the .bar file you want directly as an artifact instead of the whole build folder.

Comment: What does the pipeline log say in the build teardown about the artifact?

Comment: I tried both things, and no luck, actually I added the $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR just to try something I saw in a post

Comment: This is the output of the build teardown:
Searching for files matching artifact pattern build/**
Artifact pattern build/** matched 1 files with a total size of 5.8 KiB
Compressed files matching artifact pattern build/** to 5.8 KiB in 0 seconds
Uploading artifact of 5.8 KiB
Successfully uploaded artifact in 0 seconds
Searching for test report files in directories named [test-results, failsafe-reports, test-reports, TestResults, surefire-reports] down to a depth of 4
Finished scanning for test reports. Found 0 test report files.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out that the problem is with this line

```
. /opt/ibm/iib-10.0.0.11/server/bin/mqsipackagebar -a pipelineGenerated.bar -w . -k $PROJECT_NAME
```

If I remove this line and generate a file like this

```
echo "testing artifacts" > output.txt
```

the artifacts works just fine, don´t know exactly why with the other command is not working, but the pipeline seems to be OK